# Finding branches at which an identity holds

Tags: complex-analysis

If $\log_\theta$ is the branch $\log_\theta=ln(r)+i\Theta(r>0, \theta <\Theta<\theta +2\pi)$ for which $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$ does $\log_\theta(i^2)=2\log_\theta(i)$ hold.

Evaluating these two give $i(\pi+2k\pi)=i(\pi+4k'\pi)$ where $k,k'$ are integers. My idea is to chose a value for $k$ and find a corresponding value for $k'$ then using that to find $\theta $ but I'm getting nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, so we want $\log(i^2) = 2 \log(i)$.

By definition of the $\log$ function we have $\log(z):= \ln|z|+i arg(z)$.

Well, $\Rightarrow \log(i^2) = \ln|1| + i(\pi + 2 \pi k ) = i(\pi + 2 \pi m ) $, for $m \in \mathbb{Z}$

And, $2 \log(i) = 2(\ln|1| + i(\frac{\pi}{2}+ 2 \pi k)) = i(\pi+4 \pi k)$, for $ k \in \mathbb{Z}$

So, when is: $i(\pi + 4 \pi k) = i(\pi + 2\pi m)$? $\Rightarrow 4\pi k + \pi = \pi + 2\pi m \Rightarrow 4 \pi k - 2\pi m =0 \Rightarrow 2k-m = 0 $

Comment: I am not sure if this is what your asking for, if not give me some more background, so I can keep trying to help.

Comment: I'm asking for which branches of $\log$ does this hold. This does not answer the question, also I'm pretty sure you can't use the same $k$

Comment: Yes, you are correct,that was bad notation, but branch cuts are used make the complex log "function" single-valued, I don't see how that will tell when equality holds.

Comment: My question is out of these single valued functions which ones give $\log_\theta(i^2)=2\log_\theta(i)$

Comment: Well since your question is asking which $\theta$ values does this equality hold, for $\pi + 4 \pi k$ but if we want it in our range we need $k=0$. So this only holds for $\theta =\pi$

Comment: I was able to find that by guessing, could you please elaborate how did you get it.I mean if $k=0$ why is $\theta =\pi$

Comment: Sure no problem. From $2k-m = 0$ we have that $m =2k$. Then if we want true for $\theta \in [0,2 \pi] $ and we have $\pi + 4 \pi k$, then if k is not $0$ we get values of $\theta$ that is out of our range. For instance $k=1$ give $5 \pi k$. So immediately we see that the smallest integer $k$ that satisfies this equality is $0$.

Comment: Does this solution now satisfy your problem (if so check it off as so)? If not keep asking.

Comment: I meant when we find that $k=0$ how do we deduce that $\theta=\pi$

Comment: I think we can do better, since $\arg(i^2)=-\pi+2m\pi$ we also have $\theta < \arg(z)< \theta +2\pi$ then by setting $m=0$ we get $0<\theta<\pi$

Comment: $arg(i^2) = \pi + 2 \pi m$

Comment: In general the latter part of the complex log function is $iarg(z)$, and here $arg(z) = \pi + 2 \pi k$ thus allowing $k=0$ we get $arg(z) = \pi$

Comment: That's a typo I meant $\pi$ the same result comes out.

Comment: But $\theta=\pi$ does not work since $arg(z)=\pi$ no longer remains in the range of arguments. However if $0<\theta < \pi$ then $\arg(i^2)$ still comes out as $\pi$

Comment: It is in the range you specified.

Comment: I think you are mistaking $\theta$ for $arg(z)$

Comment: The arg(z) gives  $\theta$ values!

Comment: Yes, it determines more than $1$ value though since we necessarily have $\theta < \pi <\theta + 2\pi$ we need to solve for $\theta$ and we get $0<\theta < \pi$

Comment: I forgot to include zero it's $0\le\theta < \pi$